# Insert decimalplaces into number and the round the sum

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm new to Oracle and coming from MS SQL Server enviroment.

How do I format a column that is of type number(10) so a comma will be inserted before the last two digits, sum the formatted values and then round the sum?

**Amount column values**

```
400 (format to 4,00)
4000 (format to 40,00)
40000 (format to 400,00)
400000 (format to 4000,00)
639 (format to 6,39)
```

Sum of the formatted numbers will in this case be: 4445,39

Round the sum will return: 4445.

**The queries I've tried with:**

```
select TO_CHAR((ROUND(SUM(Amount))),'FM9999999G90')
select TO_NUMBER(ROUND((TO_CHAR(SUM(Amount),'FM9999999G90'))), '9999999.99')
```

Result: 4450.39, but I want it to be rounded to 4450 in this case.

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa0c4/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to divide the number by `100`, and then **ROUND** it:

```
 ROUND(SUM(amount)/100)
```

See this **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa0c4/43)** for a working demo:

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this doesn't round. :( ie. 4450.80 it should be 4451.

Comment: @Henrik What is the business rule? The sum(amount) of your input should ideally be `445039`. What if the value is `123456`? So, what is the rule?

Comment: The rule is that amount is of type number(10) this is a price of a product ie. But has no decimals in the db. Therefore i need to add a decimal before the 2 last digits. ie. 639 should be converted to format 6,39. After the conversion of all column values I want to sum all the values and then round the total sum. The sum should always be in format of two decimals, ie. 1234,56 and then be rounded to 1235.

Comment: @Henrik Ok, See the updated answer. Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Comment: Ahh thank you. I thought Number type was like integer and therefore need to format it to a string first. :)